# Unicode output on Windows command line?

Tags: unicode, cmd

I wrote a small Java application which output includes Unicode characters. When I use Eclipse to run it—I see all the output as expected.

The people who are supposed to use the application will run it as a jar file. I thought they could use standard cmd window, but in this window the Unicode appear as Gibberish.

Is there a way to make "cmd window" recognize the Unicode chars and display them properly?
Or, is there any tool to easily run the jar file and get the correct output?

BTW - redirecting the output to a file works okay, but the program is interactive, so this will not be a good solution.

**Edit:** Thanks everybody for the suggestions.
It seems that the cmd fonts don't have the specific characters I need, and this is why changing the code page did not solve my problem.

I found a [way](http://thesystemadministrator.com/The_System_Administrator/Tips_&_Tricks/Adding_Fonts_to_Command_Line_(cmd.exe)/) to add more monospaced fonts to the console, but after I add them any change that I want to do regarding the fonts (even choosing one of the original fonts in a different size) - is ignored.

I think that I will simply try with another tool, which supports chhosing a differnt font more easily.

Comment: I suppose you'll have to write a "console" for your application after all...

Comment: "way to add more monospaced fonts to the console" - the link is dead

Comment: [Here](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-add-fonts-to-the-command-prompt/) is a way to add more fonts. Not sure if it has the problem the OP mentioned anymore, though.

Answer (score 17):

Reference: [Java Unicode on Windows Command Line](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/java-unicode-on-windows-command-line.html)

Try `chcp 1252` or `chcp 65001` from the command line. With Lucida Console or other font support.

Comment: chcp 65001 helped in Windows 11 cmd.exe (command prompt), but not in wt.exe (PowerShell).

Answer (score 1):

try CMD /c /U java your.jar

Comment: This did not solve the problem... As far as I understand, /U influence only output of internal commands.

Comment: Also, would be cmd /U /c, otherwise "/U is not recognized as an internal or external command".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the font with which the windows console is displaying output. Unfortunately for you, this is a user setting.

I recommend you suggest that your users set their windows console font to Lucida Console. That font should be able to handle wide/unicode characters.

Comment: Even in Windows 7 the console windows default to raster fonts :-(. Very unfortunate.

Comment: I changed the font to Lucida. This did not solve the problem :(

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Dikla. I clicked -1 since this in fact, does not help.

Comment: offtopic, but i think i prefer the look of raster :)

Answer (score 1):

In `C++/C` just use this: `system("chcp 65001");`

Don't forget to change the console's font to `Lucida Console`

Answer (score 0):

For any answers, check it first. This is a simple console program, which verifies that changing the font actually does not work.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            Console.WriteLine( "日本語です" );
            Console.Write( "Finished. Press a key. " );
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I will check to see if the answer is concretely "Cannot be done". Other avenues to check: use a different shell. i.e. Powershell? I'll see if that works.

However, you could do:

```
ConsoleApplication1.exe > output.txt
notepad.exe output.txt
```

**Disclaimer**: My example is C#, but the console application should still work as such.

And view the results like that, in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

[UTF-16 on cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764920/utf-16-on-cmd-exe)

```
    Open/run cmd.exe
    Click on the icon at the top-left corner
    Select properties
    Then "Font" bar
    Select "Lucida Console" and OK.
    Write Chcp 10000 at the prompt
    Finally dir /b
```

Also from
[Is there a Windows command shell that will display Unicode characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379240/is-there-a-windows-command-shell-that-will-display-unicode-characters/24135341#24135341)

```
CHCP 65001
DIR > UTF8.TXT
TYPE UTF8.TXT
```

Comment: Does "Lucida Console" supports special chars? I tried several chars and they were displayed as a squares on the cmd window.