# Unable to process special character on command prompt

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am unable to process special characters such as (–, ', £ etc) in a java file when i try executing them on windows command prompt.

Example:

```
public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("Mangifera indica – the common mango");
   }
}
```

Expected Output: Mangifera indica – the common mango

Ouput Recieved: Mangifera indica ΓÇô the common mango

I believe it is some sort of unicode problem, and i very much want to run it on the command prompt, is there a way it could be sorted?

Comment: I can't make the information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035388/unicode-output-on-windows-command-line#answer-1035907) an answer. it would be stealing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the solution to above mentioned problem is to set the windows command prompt font to consola and activate code chcp 65001, worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

With this little program you can "brute-force" check the encoding of your console.
Your input was  `–`, resulting in output `ΓÇô`.

This program will emulate all wrong encoded outputs by trying all available charsets to generate `ΓÇô`, It just reencode the UTF-8-Bytes of `–` with an other, wrong charset:

```
String s="–";
byte[] b=s.getBytes("UTF-8");
for (Charset charset:Charset.availableCharsets().values())
{
  String p=new String(b,charset.name());
  if ("ΓÇô".equals(p))
  System.out.println(charset.aliases()+": "+p);
 }
```

Output:

> [ibm-437, windows-437, cspc8codepage437, 437, ibm437, cp437]: ΓÇô
>
> [860, cp860, ibm-860, csIBM860, ibm860]: ΓÇô
>
> [861, cp-is, ibm-861, cp861, csIBM861, ibm861]: ΓÇô
>
> [ibm863, csIBM863, cp863, 863, ibm-863]:ΓÇô
>
> [csIBM865, ibm865, 865, ibm-865, cp865]: ΓÇô

So your console runs in one of these charsets, but your System.out. is assuming UTF-8.