# Converting Devanagari Unicode to its character

Tags: java, unicode

I am trying to convert the Devanagari Unicode to its character in Java and trying to display on CMD but it gives me a `?` character.

Here is my code:

```
public class ConvertUnicode
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a = 0x0909;
        char c = (char)a;
        System.out.println("  "+c);
    }
}
```

Output of above code is a `?` character.

Comment: It is possible that your console, not the java program, is unable to output the Devanagari character, because the console font do not have the glyph.

Comment: If you write it to a File and specify "UTF8" as the encoding, how's it look?

Comment: possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035388/unicode-output-on-windows-command-line

Comment: @luiges90 nope, you get a `?` per character that cannot be encoded in target encoding.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your reply. I tried it by changing the file encoding type to "UTF8" also, I changed the console font to Lucida but still I am facing the same problem.

Comment: If any one have the code which convert Unicode to it's proper character please post it so, that I can refer the code and try to convert Devnagari unicode to it's original character.