# How do I encode Unicode character codes in a PowerShell string literal?

Tags: powershell, unicode, string-literals, unicode-literals

How can I encode the Unicode character U+0048 (H), say, in a PowerShell string?

In C# I would just do this: `"\u0048"`, but that doesn't appear to work in PowerShell.

Comment: What's your output encoding set to? ($OutputEncoding)

Comment: It's us-ascii. But U+0048 should be encodable in that. I'm actually trying to encode an escape character (U+001B).

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Replace '\u' with '0x' and cast it to System.Char:

```
PS > [char]0x0048
H
```

You can also use the "$()" syntax to embed a Unicode character into a string:

```
PS > "Acme$([char]0x2122) Company"
AcmeT Company
```

Where T is PowerShell's representation of the  character for non-registered trademarks.

Note: this method works only for characters in Plane 0, the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane), chars < U+10000.

Comment: You can even write a little function: function C($n) {[char][int]"0x$n"}. Which you can use in a string as follows: "$(C 48)ello World." Not ideal but probably a little closer to the \u escape.

Comment: This also works when you want to pass a unicode [char] to a function. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I know this topic is 2.5 years old, but following up on @Joey's comment, you can even make a function called `\u`. It's identical to Joey's, just with a different name. So the function is `function \u($n) {[char][int]"0x$n"}`. The way you call it is just like C# except that you need a space between the function name and the number. So `\u 0048` returns `H`.

Comment: This only works for characters in BMP, else it triggers an error.
Eg. `[char]0x1D400`: `InvalidArgument: Cannot convert value "119808" to type "System.Char". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for a character."`

Comment: @noraj The reason this only works for characters in the BMP is that .NET’s `char` type represents UTF-16 code units, and for BMP characters, 1 character = 1 code unit, but for non-BMP characters, 1 character = 2 code units. /// @chris the `\u` function could be extended to work with non-BMP characters.

Answer (score 32):

According to the documentation, PowerShell Core 6.0 adds support with this escape sequence:

```
PS> "`u{0048}"
H
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-6#unicode-character-ux

Answer (score 17):

Maybe this isn't the PowerShell way, but this is what I do. I find it to be cleaner.

```
[regex]::Unescape("\u0048") # Prints H
[regex]::Unescape("\u0048ello") # Prints Hello
```

Answer (score 5):

For those of us still on 5.1 and wanting to use the higher-order Unicode charset (for which none of these answers work) I made this function so you can simply build strings like so:

```
'this is my favourite park ',0x1F3DE,'. It is pretty sweet ',0x1F60A | Unicode
```

[image]

```
#takes in a stream of strings and integers,
#where integers are unicode codepoints,
#and concatenates these into valid UTF16
Function Unicode {
    Begin {
        $output=[System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
    }
    Process {
        $output.Append($(
            if ($_ -is [int]) { [char]::ConvertFromUtf32($_) }
            else { [string]$_ }
        )) | Out-Null
    }
    End { $output.ToString() }
}
```

Note that getting these to display in your console is a [whole other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/379240/2518317), but if you're outputting to an [Outlook email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) or a Gridview (below) it will just work (as utf16 is native for .NET interfaces).

[image]

This also means you can also output plain control (not necessarily unicode) characters pretty easily if you're more comfortable with decimal since you dont actually need to use the `0x` (hex) syntax to make the integers. `'hello',160,'there' | Unicode` would put a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) betwixt the two words, the same as if you did `0xA0` instead.

Comment: `[char]::ConvertFromUtf32` has been available since .NET 2.1 so you don't need such a complex function

Comment: oh neat. The function is still necessary, I'm not writing `[char]blahblahblah` whenever I want a `"\`u{}"`, but it does simplify the `if`

Comment: besides `$_ -shr 11` should be used instead of `[int][math]::Floor($_ / 0x400)`, and `($_ -band 0x3FF) -bor 0xDC00` instead of `[char]($_ % 0x400 + 0xDC00)`

Comment: I s'pose that's obvious since it was a nice even hex number, oh well. Doesn't matter now that .NET can handle the overarching problem

Answer (score 4):

To make it work for characters outside the BMP you need to use [Char.ConvertFromUtf32()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.convertfromutf32?view=netstandard-2.1)

```
'this is my favourite park ' + [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F3DE) + 
'. It is pretty sweet ' + [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F60A)
```

In PowerShell 6.0 or newer you can also use `` `u{} ``

```
"this is my favourite park `u{1F3DE}. It is pretty sweet `u{1F60A}"
```

This special character  was added in PowerShell 6.0.

> The Unicode escape sequence (`` `u{x} ``) allows you to specify any Unicode character by the hexadecimal representation of its code point. This includes Unicode characters above the Basic Multilingual Plane (> `0xFFFF`) which includes emoji characters such as the thumbs up (`` `u{1F44D} ``) character. The Unicode escape sequence requires at least one hexadecimal digit and supports up to six hexadecimal digits. The maximum hexadecimal value for the sequence is `10FFFF`.
>
> ## [Unicode character (`` `u{x} ``)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7.4#unicode-character-ux)

Comment: Yep, with emoji's in powershell you would need 2 surrogate characters in a row https://stackoverflow.com/a/70057239/6654942.

Answer (score 3):

Another way using PowerShell.

```
$Heart = $([char]0x2665)
$Diamond = $([char]0x2666)
$Club = $([char]0x2663)
$Spade = $([char]0x2660)
Write-Host $Heart -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Magenta
```

Use the command `help Write-Host -Full` to read all about it.

Comment: [Shay Levy's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1056978/995714) already showed how to use `[char]0x2665`. In fact this is **far more inefficient** because you create a new subshell for each variable instead of assigning directly: `$Heart = [char]0x2665`

Answer (score 0):

Note that some characters like  might need a "double rune" to be printed:

```
PS> "C:\foo\bar\$([char]0xd83c)$([char]0xdf0e)something.txt"
```

Will print:

```
C:\foo\bar\something.txt
```

You can find these "runes" here, in the "unicode escape" row: https://dencode.com/string

Comment: no need for such a complex manual lookup method. My answer already shows many solutions before you. `` "C:\foo\bar\`u{1F30E}something.txt" `` or `"C:\foo\bar\" + [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F30E) + "something.txt"` will work