# Join string with non-breaking space in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I try to

```
$arr = "one", "two"
$test = [String]::Join(@"\u00A0", $arr)
```

and it gives me

```
Unrecognized token in source text.
```

Is it because i have to specify it in **utf-8** as `0xC2 0xA0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `@` char - it is not *here-string*.

```
[String]::Join("\u00A0", $arr)
```

Added after S.Mark's answer:

I'll add because S.Mark already posted answer, that can be accepted,
that *here-strings* begin with `@`. Try to google them. And - it's somewhat different to C#. You don't escape with `\`, but with backtick. So probably the string should be something like "`u00A0", but I'm not sure...

**Solution**

After some hanging around stack overflow, I found Shay's answer that probably is what you wanted.

```
[String]::Join([char]0x00A0, $arr)
```

or maybe

```
$arr -join [char]0x00A0
```

[Shay's answer how to escape unicode character.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056692/how-to-encode-unicode-character-codes-in-a-powershell-string-literal)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i was looking for but i got stuck casting the unicode to char.

Comment: In case it isn't obvious from the post (which guesses more than anything else): PowerShell has no Unicode escape method inside of strings, so yes, the only useful way to do this is by casting an integer to a `char`.

Answer (score 2):

You would not need `@` before "\u00A0"

```
PS > $arr = "one", "two"

PS > $test = [String]::Join(@"\u00A0", $arr)
Unrecognized token in source text.

PS > $test = [String]::Join("\u00A0", $arr)
PS >
PS > $test
one\u00A0two
```

Comment: This just explains the error but didn't help me to join with a non-breaking space, so stej gets marker. Thanks for your support nonetheless.