# PowerShell Hash Tables Double Key Error: "a" and "A"

Tags: powershell, hashtable

from another application I have key-value pairs which I want to use in my script.
But there they have e.g. the keys "a" and "A" - which causes an Error double keys aren't allowed.

```
  $x = @{ "a" = "Entry for a"; "A" = "S.th.else for A" }
```

What can I do as I would need both or none?

Thanks in advance,
Gooly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default PowerShell Hash tables are case sensitive.
Try this

```
$h = new-object System.Collections.Hashtable
$h['a'] = "Entry for a"
$h['A'] = "S.th.else for A"
$h[0] = "Entry for 0"
$h[1] = "Entry for 1"
$h
```

Output for $h: (it will treat `a` and `A` differently)

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
A                              S.th.else for A
a                              Entry for a
1                              Entry for 1
0                              Entry for 0
```

Or this (depending on the syntax that you prefer)

```
$hash = New-Object system.collections.hashtable
$hash.a = "Entry for a"
$hash.A = "S.th.else for A"
$hash.0 = "Entry for 0"
$hash.1 = "Entry for 1"
$hash.KEY
$hash
```

But, if you create hashtable with `@{}` syntax. It is case insensitive

```
$x = @{}
$x['a'] = "Entry for a"
$x['A'] = "S.th.else for A"
$x[0] = "Entry for 0"
$x[1] = "Entry for 1"
$x
```

Output for $x: (it will treat `a` and `A` as same)

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
a                              S.th.else for A
1                              Entry for 1
0                              Entry for 0
```

Note: Both `$h.GetType()` and `$x.GetType()` are of `System.Object.Hashtable`

Comment: ok - this works for "a" and "A" but now the keys 0..9 aren't accepted :(

Comment: I have tested code with keys 0..9 and works. I have edited answer to show that...

Comment: But this works:  $hash.Add("0","...");  $hash.Add("a","...");   $hash.Add("A","...");

Comment: if: $hash = New-Object system.collections.hashtable
$hash.0 = "Check 0"
I get: + $hash.0 <<<<  = "Check 0"
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (.0:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Even accessing $hash.0 doesn't work, but $s="0";$hash.$s; gives me the value behind "0".

Comment: Output of the above $h is having 4 keys (both `a` and `A` are present). Which means it is treating `a` and `A` differently. So it is case sensitive. Am i right ? @OscarFoley (If it right, we have to change the first line in your answer, by removing word `not`)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a case-sensitive powerhsell hash table using `System.Collections.Hashtable`

```
$x = New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable 
$x['a']="Entry for a"
$x['A']="S.th.else for A"
```