# Powershell, can't enter hashtable keys with some non-ASCII characters (in a script)

Tags: powershell, utf-8, character-encoding, char, hashtable

I'm trying to create a PowerShell hash table to convert non-ASCII (UTF8) characters to their ASCII look-a-likes.

Here are two hash table entries as examples:  `'ñ'='n'` and `'Ñ'='N'`.

<sup>Editor's note: Using *both* theses entries in the *same* hash table literal (`@{ 'ñ'='n'; 'Ñ'='N' }`) wouldn't work, because PowerShell uses hash tables with case-*insensitive* key lookups and therefore considers `'ñ'` and `'Ñ'`*duplicate* keys and complains. However, this is *incidental* to the problem at hand.</sup>

The first one works: `'ñ'` is `0xc3b1`. The second one does not work: `'Ñ'` is `0xc391` which PowerShell won't accept. (The problem seems to be that `0x91` is outside the range of an acceptable powershell char.)

A simpler example of the problem is:

```
$c = [convert]::toChar(0x91)
```

which results in `$c` getting a value of `0x3f` instead of `0x91`.  So what can I do to get `'Ñ'='N'` into the
hash table, or a char with a value of `0x91`? I've already spent hours reading web pages and experimenting.

Comment: According to PowerShell, `[char]0xc391` is Korean character sselt `쎑`, try `[char]0x00D1` which is the utf-16 character. https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00F1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell Hash Tables Double Key Error: "a" and "A"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054147/powershell-hash-tables-double-key-error-a-and-a)

Comment: @7cc isn't this about Unicode not duplicate elements in a hashtable?

Comment: Powershell 7 gives a better error message:  `Duplicate keys 'Ñ' are not allowed in hash literals.`

Comment: @NekoMusume utf16 and unicode are 2 different things, but microsoft makes it confusing

Comment: @js2010 Windows PowerShell emits the same error message. The primary problem here is unrelated to (case-insensitively) duplicate hash-table keys; it is a _character encoding_ problem, stemming from the fact that Windows PowerShell (mis)reads BOM-less UTF-8 files as ANSI-encoded.

Comment: @js2010 I've edited the question to make it clearer, but my previous comment still applies: the question isn't about duplicate keys, and both PS editions use the same error message.

Comment: You're right about powershell versions.  I guess my colors in one were harder to read.  I would guess that he's reading the hashtables from a file?  But there's no info about that in the question.

Comment: Tom, I've added an explanation for the `[convert]::toChar(0x91)` behavior to the answer.

Comment: @js2010 There's no information about reading from a file (meaning: PowerShell reading a `*.ps1` file containing source code with a hash-table literal for execution) in the _question_, because Tom didn't realize that's where the problem was. My _answer_ clarifies that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: By default, PowerShell hashtables, due to using case-*insensitive* lookups, do not support keys that are mere *case variations* of another; therefore, `ñ` and `Ñ` - the former being the lowercase version of the latter - cannot *both* be used as keys - see bottom section.

---

**In *memory*, all PowerShell strings are UTF-16 .NET strings, which are capable of representing *all* Unicode characters**, so using character such as `Ñ` as keys in hash tables is *not* a problem.

**The problem you describe only arises when PowerShell *misinterprets* source code read *from a file***, due to assuming the wrong character encoding.

Your symptom suggests that your source code is UTF-8-encoded, but the file *doesn't have a BOM*, which causes *Windows PowerShell* (but, fortunately, no longer PowerShell [Core] v6+) to misinterpret the file as encoded based on the system's active legacy ANSI code page (e.g., Windows-1252 on US-English systems), a single-byte encoding.

**Make sure that your source-code file is saved as UTF-8 *with a BOM***<sup>[1]</sup>, and your problem will go away.

What you think are Unicode code points, `0xc3b1` and `0xc391`, are in reality the 2-byte *UTF-8* encodings (`0xc3 0xb1` and `0xc3 91`) of the true code points corresponding to `ñ` and `Ñ`: [`0xf1`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f1) and [`0xd1`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d1)

---

As for:

> `[convert]::toChar(0x91)`

seemingly *not* producing a `[char]` instance with the given code point, `0x91` (decimal `145`):

- It *does*, namely *in memory*, which you can easily verify:

  ```
    [int] [convert]::toChar(0x91) # -> 145 (0x91)
  ```
- You'll only get `0x3f` - which is a literal `?` character (try `[char] 0x3f`) - if you mistakenly save the in-memory representation with ASCII encoding: since `0x91` is outside the ASCII sub-range of Unicode (which goes from `0x00` to `0x7f`), it cannot be represented in the output file, and the *substitute character* `?` is used.

---

Note that **PowerShell's hash tables are case-*insensitive***, so you **cannot have keys that are merely *case variations* of one another**:

```
# !! FAILS
PS> @{ Ñ = 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE'; ñ = 'LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE' }
...  Duplicate keys 'ñ' are not allowed in hash literals.
```

You must use the .NET `[hashtable]` type (`System.Collections.Hashtable`) *directly* to create case-*sensitive* hash tables:

```
# Create case-SENSITIVE hash table:
$ht = [hashtable]::new()
$ht['ñ'] = 'LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE' 
$ht['Ñ'] = 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE'
```

- `$ht` now has *2* entries and `$ht['ñ']` and `$ht['Ñ']` retrieve the values case-sensitively.
- By contrast, if you had used `$ht = @{}`, i.e. initialized the hash table as a regular, case-*insensitive* hash table, you'd only get *1* entry with value `'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE'`, because the 2nd assignment, `$ht['Ñ'] =`, simply *updated* the case-insensitively looked-up key created by the 1st statement.

---

<sup>[1] Alternatively, use a UTF-16 encoding, which *invariably* uses a BOM; the UTF-16LE form is (erroneously) referred to as `Unicode` in PowerShell.</sup>