# Spliting an emoji sequence in powershell

Tags: powershell, unicode, emoji, surrogate-pairs

I have a text box that will be filled with emoji only. No spaces or characters of any kind. I need to split these emoji in order to identify them. This is what I have tried:

```
function emoji_to_unicode(){
    foreach ($emoji in $textbox.Text) {
        $unicode = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($emoji)
        Write-Host $unicode
    }
}
```

Instead of printing the bytes one by one, the loop is running just once, printing the codes of all the emoji joined together. It's like all the emoji was a single item. I tested with 6 emoji, and instead of getting this:

61 216 7 222

61 216 67 222

61 216 10 222

61 216 28 222

61 216 86 220

60 216 174 223

I'm getting this:

61 216 7 222 61 216 67 222 61 216 10 222 61 216 28 222 61 216 86 220 60 216 174 223

What am I missing?

Comment: Windows PowerShell or PowerShell Core?

Comment: Windows PowerShell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string is just one element.  You want to change it to a character array.

```
foreach ($i in 'hithere') { $i }
hithere

foreach ($i in [char[]]'hithere') { $i }
h
i
t
h
e
r
e
```

Hmm this doesn't work well.  These code points are pretty high, U+1F600 (32-bit), etc

```
foreach ($i in [char[]]'') { $i }       
�  # 16 bit surrogate pairs?
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
```

Hmm ok, add every pair.  Here's another way to do it using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates (or just use ConvertToUTF32($emoji, 0) )

```
$emojis = ''
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $emojis.length; $i += 2) {
  [System.Char]::IsHighSurrogate($emojis[$i])
  0x10000 + ($emojis[$i] - 0xD800) * 0x400 + $emojis[$i+1] - 0xDC00 | % tostring x
  # [system.char]::ConvertToUtf32($emojis,$i) | % tostring x  # or
  $emojis[$i] + $emojis[$i+1]
}


True
1f600

True
1f601

True
1f602

True
1f603

True
1f604

True
1f605

True
1f606
```

Note that *unicode* in the Unicode.GetBytes() method call refers to *utf16le* encoding.

Chinese works.

```
[char[]]'嗨，您好'
嗨
，
您
好
```

Here it is using utf32 encoding. All characters are 4 bytes long.  Converting every 4 bytes into an int32 and printing them as hex.

```
$emoji = ''
$utf32 = [System.Text.Encoding]::utf32.GetBytes($emoji)

for($i = 0; $i -lt $utf32.count; $i += 4) {
    $int32 = [bitconverter]::ToInt32($utf32[$i..($i+3)],0)
    $int32 | % tostring x
}

1f600
1f601
1f602
1f603
1f604
1f605
1f606
```

Or going the other way from int32 to string.  Simply casting the int32 to `[char]` does not work (have to add pairs of [char]'s).  Script reference:  https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Emojis/0.1/Content/Emojis.psm1

```
for ($i = 0x1f600; $i -le 0x1f606; $i++ ) { [System.Char]::ConvertFromUtf32($i) }
```

See also [How to encode 32-bit Unicode characters in a PowerShell string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834291/how-to-encode-32-bit-unicode-characters-in-a-powershell-string-literal)

EDIT:

Powershell 7 has a nice enumeraterunes() method:

```
$emojis = ''
$emojis.enumeraterunes() | % value | % tostring x

1f600
1f601
1f602
1f603
1f604
1f605
1f606
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution   <sub><sup>*works on both PowerShell 5.1  &  7.4  !!*</sup></sub>

```
$str = 'hithere'

[Globalization.StringInfo]::GetTextElementEnumerator($str) | &{process{
  # SURROGATE PAIR HAS LENGTH OF 2
  if( $_.Length -eq 2 ){
    $highSurr, $lowSurr = [char[]]$_ -as 'int[]'
    $surrPair = ($highSurr - 0xD800) * 0x400 + $lowSurr - 0xDC00 + 0x10000
    "{0} `t 0x{1:X} `t 0x{2:X} + 0x{3:X}" -f $_, $surrPair, $highSurr, $lowSurr
  }
  elseif( $_.Length -eq 1 ){
    "{0} `t 0x{1:X4}" -f $_, [int][char]$_
  }
}}
```

### Result

```
h    0x0068
i    0x0069
t    0x0074
h    0x0068
e    0x0065
r    0x0072
e    0x0065
   0x1F600     0xD83D + 0xDE00
   0x1F601     0xD83D + 0xDE01
   0x1F602     0xD83D + 0xDE02
   0x1F603     0xD83D + 0xDE03
   0x1F604     0xD83D + 0xDE04
   0x1F605     0xD83D + 0xDE05
   0x1F606     0xD83D + 0xDE06
```

<sup>*(Any misalignment is the fault of the way the site is rendered; it should be aligned in your terminal.)*</sup>

### How It Works

First we use the C# method `[Globalization.StringInfo]::GetTextElementEnumerator` to split the string into an array of Unicode characters; then, in the pipeline, we determine if it's a surrogate pair.

If it **is** a surrogate pair, we assign the high surrogate & low surrogate variables by casting the pipeline object into an array of `char` objects (limited to UTF-8 values), then cast it into an `int` array.

After that, we create a variable for the UTF-16 value through the use of a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_from_U+010000_to_U+10FFFF) involving the high surrogate and low surrogate values.

Finally, we print the values using an [f-string](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) with hex formatting (using a lowercase `X` makes the letters within the hex value lowercase & vice versa).

If it **isn't** a surrogate pair, we simply cast the pipeline object into a `char` and then an `int`. We again use an f-string to print the value with hex formatting, but we give it a padding of `4` (placed right after the `X`) so values like `0x68` are instead printed as `0x0068`.

Comment: Nice...........

Comment: @js2010 Posted a slight revision: `$_.Length -eq 2` is much simpler than `[Char]::IsSurrogatePair`, not sure why I didn't think of that before... though I suppose `[Char]::IsSurrogatePair` is clearer without needing a comment. However, I don't completely trust `[Char]` methods, as they tend to be kept out-of-date for backward-compatibility purposes.