# How to insert a soft hyphen

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like to insert a soft hyphen between every letter in a word using powershell. for example here is some text:

```
Thisisatest => T-h-i-s-i-s-a-t-e-s-t
```

`-` is a soft hyphen. How might i do this in powershell?

Comment: I kind of thought that `-` was just a hyphen. What would be a **hard** hyphen?

Comment: @Yuck http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen - and what Luke101 is doing is actually a hard hyphen, not a soft one. A hard hyphen stays with the text no matter what, as in mother-in-law.

Comment: @L.B You can write C# cmdlets to do stuff in Powershell.

Comment: A soft hyphen would be ‘­’. You probably won’t see it in a browser, but if you copy-and-paste my previous sentence to Notepad, it will automagically appear. If you’re on Windows, you might be able to create it by typing Alt+0173.

Comment: Here is a good link to look at in regards to Scripting with PowerShell.. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using .NET methods a little more than canonical PowerShell code, you can write

```
$word = "Thisisatest"
[System.String]::Join("-", $word.ToCharArray())
```

and Powershell outputs "T-h-i-s-i-s-a-t-e-s-t"

EDIT: For a true soft hyphen, and using [this answer on Unicode in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056692/how-to-encode-unicode-character-codes-in-a-powershell-string-literal), I would change the second line to

```
[System.String]::Join([char] 0x00AD, $word.ToCharArray())
```

Comment: That's odd.  On my box (Windows 7, PowerShell 2.0), I get the correct string output

Comment: ouch! same box! how debug this now??

Comment: Which of the two posted lines are you using?  The one with "-", or the one with [char] 0x00AD?

Comment: Try the line: `[System.String]::Join("-", @('T', 'h', 'i', 's'))`  The `@` explicitly creates an array.

Comment: How about `$a = $word.ToCharArray()` followed by `[System.String]::Join("-", $a)`?

Comment: vs2010?  I think you have something else going on to cause the weird output.  In plain PowerShell you shouldn't get that result at all.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the PowerShell-friendly -join operator to do this:

```
"Thisisatest".ToCharArray() -join '-'
```

Look at the PowerShell Technet help for more information about the -join PowerShell operator.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315375.aspx

Comment: Or [char[]]"Thisisatest" -join '-'

Answer (score 2):

There is a great article on splitting and joining strings in PowerShell [here](http://tasteofpowershell.blogspot.com/2009/08/string-manipulation-splitting-and.html).

You may also find that the `string.ToCharacterArray` method is useful, as mentioned [here](http://%24d%20=%20%24e.ToCharArray%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

My Prof. PowerShell column on the topic of splitting and joining:
http://mcpmag.com/articles/2011/10/18/split-and-join-operators.aspx

Personally, I think you should avoid using .NET classes and methods unless there is no "native" PowerShell cmdlet or operator.