# Issue using Framework 4.0 in Powershell with [system.string]::join

Tags: powershell, .net-4.0

Starting from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165664/how-to-insert-a-soft-hyphen) I discovered that using the `powershell.exe.config` to load .net Framework 4.0 runtime, this code:

```
$word = "Thisisatest"
[System.String]::Join("-", $word.ToCharArray())
```

return `System.Char[]`

Executing Powershell w/o `powershell.exe.config` the same code works in the right way.

Someone can reproduce this issue and explain why??

My box is windows 7 pro with Powershell 2.0

Edit: my `powershell.exe.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
         <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>        
         <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>        
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post your `powershell.exe.config` ?

Comment: Well at least I could reproduce on Windows XP 32bit w/ PS 2.0. When I commented out `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>` it returned the data instead of the type as expected so it has something to do with that.

Comment: @AndyArismendi. Thank you for trying to reproduce it. Now I'm sure that is loading .net 4.0 runtime the issue. Some conflict in type call maybe?

Comment: So this works `[string]::Join("-" , (1,2,3))`. It's just that `ToCharArray` method. It could be an issue with `DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml` or just a bug. You might want to check the  [Microsoft PowerShell Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell) site.

Comment: yes. Doesn't work only with char[]! (1,2,3) is an object[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the new overloads to [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) added in version 4 of the .NET framework:

```powershell
PS> [Environment]::Version.ToString()
2.0.50727.5456
PS> [string]::Join.OverloadDefinitions
static string Join(string separator, string[] value)
static string Join(string separator, string[] value, int startIndex, int count)
```

```powershell
PS> [Environment]::Version.ToString()
4.0.30319.269
PS> [string]::Join.OverloadDefinitions
static string Join(string separator, Params string[] value)
static string Join(string separator, Params System.Object[] values)
static string Join[T](string separator, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[T] values)
static string Join(string separator, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[string] values)
static string Join(string separator, string[] value, int startIndex, int count)
```

---

In .NET 2.0, the only applicable method overload takes a `string[]` as the second argument, so each character from `$word.ToCharArray()` is coerced to a string.

```powershell
PS> Trace-Command *Member* { [string]::Join( "-", $word.ToCharArray() ) } -PSHost
...
MemberResolution: Method argument conversion.
MemberResolution:     Converting parameter "-" to "System.String".
MemberResolution: Method argument conversion.
MemberResolution:     Converting parameter "System.Char[]" to "System.String[]".
MemberResolution: Calling Method: static string Join(string separator, string[] value)
```

In .NET 4, the `object[]` overload is preferred. Rather than boxing each character, the entire array is coerced to an object, sending a single-element object array to `string.Join`, which then has `ToString` called to produce the `"System.Char[]"` output.

```powershell
Method argument conversion.
    Converting parameter "-" to "System.String".
Method argument conversion.
    Converting parameter "System.Char[]" to "System.Object".
Method argument conversion.
    Converting parameter "System.Object[]" to "System.Object[]".
Calling Method: static string Join(string separator, Params System.Object[] values)
```

To get the old behavior, you can insert a `[string[]]` cast to influence how the method is resolved (or in this case just use PowerShell's `-join` operator, which works correctly everywhere :).

```powershell
PS> $word = 'test'
PS> [string]::Join( '-', $word.ToCharArray() )
System.Char[]
PS> [string]::Join( '-', [string[]]$word.ToCharArray() )
t-e-s-t
PS> [char[]]$word -join '-'
t-e-s-t
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the solution I provided in the other question. That is the PowerShell supported method of achieving what you want to do:

```
"Thisisatest".ToCharArray() -join '-'
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315375.aspx

Comment: This doesn't produce the same output as Christian's snippet (`T-h-i-s-i-s-a-t-e-s-t`).

Comment: @Trevor - Thank you but I don't need a workaround. Is'nt my question, but thank you anyways