# unicode strings

Tags: regex

How can i convert strings in files to utf-8 with power shell?

Comment: what have you tried? what did not work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

I like this unescape solution.  See also [How do I encode Unicode character codes in a PowerShell string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056692/how-do-i-encode-unicode-character-codes-in-a-powershell-string-literal)

```
[regex]::unescape('\u2603')   # unicode snowman

☃ 

[regex]::unescape('\u0068\u006f\u006d\u0065')

home

get-content file | foreach { [regex]::unescape($_) } | 
  set-content file2
```

Comment: @js2010 I see - makes sense, re-reading the question. @kwapster: Perhaps something like the following (use with caution, because it overwrites the files - also note that the encoding may change) `Get-ChildItem C:\folder -File | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Unescape((Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $_.fullname)) | Set-Content -NoNewLine $_.FullName }`