# How can I store Cyrillic characters in a char

Tags: c++, char, ascii

How do I store a Cyrillic letter in a `char`? Because a char stores the data using ASCII, but that doesn't include Cyrillic characters(ex: йцукенгшщз). So how can I store Cyrillic letters in a char?

Comment: @IanRoberts, C++ I'd imagine since that's what he's tagged the question as.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Unicode in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010739/how-to-use-unicode-in-c)

Comment: @user3507600 at the time I posted my comment the question only had two tags - `char` and `ascii`

Comment: @IanRoberts, ah, well in that case you really didn't know did you.

Comment: If you don't want to rewrite your code to use wide characters, UTF-8 is a good way to store Unicode strings in a C string compatible format:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I don't understood question, but try to use right codepage. CP1251 / OEM 866 / KOI8-R?
There exists some codepages that may be supported by viewers and that allows to store and represent any Cyrillic symbol in single char.