# string vector not returning correct output

Tags: c++, text

```
ifstream file(path);
while (getline(file, line))
    words.push_back(line);
```

Everything works fine with this, but when I read special letters from the text file, such as "**é**clair"it reads out as "Ã©clair."

How do I solve this?

Comment: you can try [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how)

Comment: You are looking for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3019339/2405914

Comment: Code page mismatch...