# Create file in a specific Unicode path

Tags: c++, windows, file, unicode, widechar

I want to create a file with the given location path that contains Unicode characters. I've tried the below code but after compiling my code no file is generated.

```
wchar_t path = (wchar_t)"D:/File/ফোল্ডার/filename.txt";
std::wofstream file(&path); //open in constructor
std::wstring dat((wchar_t*)"Data to Write");
file << dat;
```

Comment: It says "wchar_t do not equal Unicode." You can check the documentation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010739/how-to-use-unicode-in-c/3019339

Answer (score 4):

`"D:/File/ফোল্ডার/filename.txt"` is a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) of type `const char [N]`. So `(wchar_t)"D:/File/ফোল্ডার/filename.txt"` cast a `const char *` pointer to `wchar_t` which doesn't do what you want

Besides `wchar_t path` declare a *single* wide character and not a string of wchar_t

You need to use the `L` prefix to get a string literal of `wchar_t`, and declare a pointer instead:

```
const wchar_t* path = L"D:/File/ফোল্ডার/filename.txt";
std::wofstream file(path); //open in constructor
std::wstring dat(L"Data to Write");
file << dat;
```

Also note that the default path separator on Windows is backslash `\` and not slash `/`, although for many APIs they behave the same.

Comment: Thanks, after applied your suggestion file has been created but no content written inside the file. How i do that?

Comment: `std::wstring dat(L"Data to Write");`  - here's a hint.  If you have to explicitly cast, you're probably doing it wrong. :)

Comment: of course the data must also be in `wchar_t*` like this `file << L"Data to Write"`

Comment: my mistake, i've already applied and file created with content but one more help needed, if i use parameter/variable then how i use `L` before variable?
say 
std::string ss = "D:/File/ফোল্ডার/filename.txt";
const wchar_t* path = L???;

Comment: @Md.ZakirHossain you need to [convert `std::string` to `std::wstring`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2573834/995714). But try to use `std::wstring` from the start to avoid the cost of runtime conversion