# Can a powershell script output a (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ to the console?

Tags: powershell, unicode

Can I output unicode, like the classic deskflip `(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻` to the console?

Do I have to set this 'mode' in the cli when i run the script, or could I do some magic in the script itself so the consumers of my script don't need to remember to do anything funky in the CLI?

this is my screenshot ....

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing Unicode Characters to Powershell Prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5796339/1630171).

Comment: It's strange... everything else I've read indicates that Powershell is basically a .Net language and uses UTF-16, which should have no problem with this. But try to make it work, even when I specifically create a UTF-16 .ps1 file with the correct characters, and it's not so simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of the console rather than a limitation of Powershell. If you use a different Powershell host (e.g. the Powershell ISE) then the output will appear as you expect:

```
PS C:\> write-host "(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻"
(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻
```

If you try that in the console window you actually get the same characters output (as you can tell if you copy/paste into something that will display them).