# Trying to print "white smiling face" using UTF-16 character code \u263A

Tags: java

I am trying to print the "white smiling face" to the console window using the following line of code in Java:

```
System.out.println( '\u263A' );
```

I do not get Smiley but some other character that looks a little like a question mark.

I am running the Windows 7 Pro operating system using jdk and jre versions 1.8.0_66  Any hints as to why?

Note: I am using the Consolas font in the console window which maps the code to the ideograph according to the character map dialogue.

Comment: your command prompt may have different coding like ISO-XXXX

Comment: You can output exactly the same 16-bit "Unicode code point" to a Windows command prompt, a notepad text file, a Linux terminal or an MS-Word file ... and you might see four different "characters" rendered.  Extraordinarily helpful link: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a problem in your code.  As commenters have pointed out, there is a difference between writing a Unicode code point and how your applications or OS choose to render a sequence of bytes as a character.  Here is what I get on Mac:

```
> javac TestWhiteSmilingFace.java && java TestWhiteSmilingFace
☺
```

The Windows console does not support Unicode output though.  Instead, it operates on Windows [Code Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317752(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you are willing to pipe output to a separate file and then open it in Notepad, then here is an approach that has worked successfully for me.

1. Start cmd.exe with the `/U` option.  As discussed in [cmd documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true), This option forces command output redirected to a file to be in Unicode.
2. Redirect the command output to a file, i.e. `java TestWhiteSmilingFace > TestWhiteSmilingFace.txt`.
3. Open the file in Notepad, i.e. `notepad TestWhiteSmilingFace.txt`.

This prior answer discusses the Windows console Unicode limitation in more detail and also suggests using the [PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819514.aspx) as a potential workaround.

[Printing Unicode characters to the PowerShell prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796339/printing-unicode-characters-to-powershell-prompt)

Comment: Thanks Chris. Key was " Windows console does not support Unicode." There is another good discussion on this same topic at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using