# Displaying UTF-8 Characters in Powershell Console

Tags: powershell, utf-8

**Goal:**

I am attempting to use UTF-8 characters in my code. However they are not rendering correctly in powershell.

**For example:**

```
function Go-Left{
Write-Host '⏩Left'
}

PS > Go-Left
```

**Problem:**

This will print 'Left', but it also replaces ⏩ with a box that contains a question mark. Which is a generic character for displaying an 'unrenderable character'.

**Question:**

Is there any way to display these characters in powershell?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379240/is-there-a-windows-command-shell-that-will-display-unicode-characters  I would mark as a dupe but it would appear that the answer is "Use Powershell 2.0+" which I assume you are already doing so guessing I'm missing something.

Comment: Works in ISE but not console : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796339/printing-unicode-characters-to-powershell-prompt

Comment: Deleted my answer because @sodawillow 's link says basically the same thing.