# Powershell GetValue is returning gibberish

Tags: .net, powershell

Why does this:

```
$RegistryKeys = (Get-ChildItem 
    HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VMSMP\Parameters\NicList)

foreach ($subKey in $RegistryKeys) {$subKey.GetValue("FriendlyName")}
```

Return this (text surrounded by asterisks are gibberish characters):

```
Corp **j**
LitwareInc Perimeter External **䑀**
LitwareInc Perimeter Internal **䑀**
LitwareInc Perimeter2 External
LitwareInc Perimeter2 Internal
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not gibberish. They're multi-byte Unicode characters, which don't display properly in a cmd window.

See the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379240/is-there-a-windows-command-shell-that-will-display-unicode-characters) for a solution.