# Git Error. When I run my code I get errors that shouldn't be there

Tags: git

Spontaneously when I started working on a project earlier today a function that was working perfectly fine earlier simply failed. This was curious because the last time I was working on it, it was working fine.

All that was left to do was revert to an earlier stage of the project in which I know for a fact that my function was working.

I reverted to several previous stages and the function still was not functioning.

Other people when they cloned my work found that it is functioning fine. It is only when I try to access it that it doesn't work.

The only lead I have is that my git was not functioning properly earlier. I think a file was corrupted and I fixed it by resetting my working repository and copying over my work.

Everything seemed fine after this fix.My function was working when I pushed it to github.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the errors are? :P Please post more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out somehow when I was pulling my files were being interpreted in ASCII instead of Unicode. A simple git command sorted it out.

Comment: sorry I'm no help, I fixed it ages ago but this link seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651975/unicode-utf-8-with-git-bash

Comment: OK, what version of Git are you using, and, out of the answer you mention, which command did you use?

Answer (score 1):

> Other people when they cloned my work found that it is functioning fine

The first workaround to check would be to clone the repo in a new location, and see if the corruption persists there.