# Why does Git Bash not display my PHP strings correctly?

Tags: php, utf-8, git-bash

Here is an example:

PHP:

```
<?php
echo "ção";
?>
```

Git Bash:

```
$ php a.php
├º├úo
```

Note: I'm writing a text-console application for Windows.

Comment: character sets. your terminal is probably set to a diff charset than whatever charset those chars were written into the file as.

Comment: Could You provide source of a.php converted to HEX and encoding used by Your console?

Comment: @Michas 3c3f7068700d0a6563686f2022e7e36f223b0d0a3f3e . I'm on Git Bash, I read it's already working with UTF-8.

Comment: @MarcB Any idea how to find out what that charset is? The terminal is of Git Bash.

Comment: An old answer to a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651975/unicode-utf-8-with-git-bash - may help if you're on Windows

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks. I still don't see why it doesn't just work it it's UTF-8 compliant already.

Comment: It looks your php file is encoded in CP-1252. Problematic letters have codes e7 and e3. These would be the 3-byte prefixes in UTF-8. I don't understand the encoding of Your Git Bash.

Comment: Is your Windows console font is Lucida? Also try with a more recent Git For Windows (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/)

Comment: @Michas I set the file as UTF-8 in Notepad++..

Comment: @VonC I'm on Consolas and tried other fonts. I'm in a very recent Git version.. Thanks

Comment: @PedroSobota Is it the 2.3.5 from https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/?

Comment: @Pedro-Sobota What is purpose of Your code? Do You want to write a text-console application for Windows? If so, You should edit Your question.

Comment: @VonC No, msysgit. I went ahead and uninstalled msysgit and installed git-for-windows and the problem is solved, although the Git Bash is a little different.. (I thought the official "Git" distribution for Windows was already for Windows?) Thanks

Comment: @PedroSobota Great. I have added an answer to include this conclusion.

Comment: @PedroSobota for the difference between the two "Git for Windows", see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17810334/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/784743/6309, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3144417/6309.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bash console has changed with the more recent [msys2-based](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17810334/6309) (64-bits) [Git For Windows 2.3.5](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

The OP reports:

> I went ahead and uninstalled msysgit and installed git-for-windows and the problem is solved, although the Git Bash is a little different..

That more recent version of Git For Windows includes all the [latest utf-8 support improvements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5855213/6309) and a bash 4.3.33 2013 (vs. a bash 3.1.20 2005)