# Atom can't use GitHub?

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

I have been using atom integrated to git/GitHub, and I was trying to push commit to the remote repo. Then, it returns a error that the tip of local repo is behind remote repo. I have tried fetching, pulling, and pushing multiple times and tried to do so in safe mode and force push but no luck. I did not do anything to the remote repo. I do not have access to the git command line. There is multiple branches, and one of the branch is modified.

Also, doing anything related to the git(loading state, history, etc.) from a package will output this error:

```
'git' �́A���R�}���h�܂��͊O���R�}���h�A
����\�ȃv���O�����܂��̓o�b�` �t�@�C���Ƃ��ĔF������Ă��܂���B
```

I don't really get what it is... The directory has two-byte characters in username.

Addition: OS is in japanese.

Comment: does the text shown properly on other text editor? i do wonder if you could share your repo link here. i think its related to the selected [encoding on the editor](https://imgur.com/a/rPPiX). you can set it on the right corner of the status bar.

Comment: @BagusTesa Here is the repo(happens for any repo tho) https://github.com/Naruyoko/many-to-do-less-you-have-to. I was editing branch α0.0.4. And no, the text didn't show up properly on other text editors.

Comment: Check if you see core.autocrlf true in ~/.gitconfig. What is your OS? What is your Git version?

Comment: @VonC OS is Windows 10, I don't really know what git version it is but pretty sure the newest.

Comment: @VonC And, I don't see core.autocrlf in the .gitconfig.

Comment: sorry, i just got the time to see your repo. it seems you don't have unicode characters there.. i do wonder if it caused by the environment.. could you add the version of the git and how you installed that into the question? it is part of their [known issues](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Git-for-Windows-Unicode-Support#Known_Issues) that they did not fully support unicode. you might need to fiddle with some [configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36692549/4648586).

Comment: Sort of resolved. Pushed from GitHub Desktop and it worked.