# Mocha - checkmark √ being printed as ΓêÜ on Git Bash

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I just set up some Mocha tests for some APIs and when running them the checkmark for the test execution is being printed as ΓêÜ ..

Example:

```
  test description 
    ΓêÜ (C10931) hit endpoint (74ms)
```

Expected :

```
  test description
    √ (C10931) hit endpoint (74ms)
```

I was wondering what could be causing this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Probably a unicode issue, this question might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651975/unicode-utf-8-with-git-bash

Comment: Thanks 
```chcp.com 65001``` solved the issue