# How to see all functions in a Module

Tags: julia

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra;                                                                   
a = [b; for b in names(LinearAlgebra)]
131-element Vector{Symbol}:
 :/
 :Adjoint
 :BLAS
 :Bidiagonal
 :BunchKaufman
 :Cholesky
 :CholeskyPivoted
 :ColumnNorm
 :Diagonal
 :Eigen
 :Factorization
 :GeneralizedEigen
 :GeneralizedSVD
 :GeneralizedSchur
 :Hermitian
 :Hessenberg
 :I
 ⋮
 :schur
 :schur!
 :svd
 :svd!
 :svdvals
 :svdvals!
 :sylvester
 :tr
 :transpose
 :transpose!
 :tril
 :tril!
 :triu
 :triu!
 :×
 :⋅

julia> clipboard(a)

julia> using Markdown

julia> clipboard(Markdown.plain(a))
```

The last two operators are not visible in the command line. What exactly are they?

Update: The following code is giving clue:

```
julia> Unicode.julia_chartransform(eval(a[end]))                                                                          
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching julia_chartransform(::typeof(dot))                                                 
                                                                                                                          
Closest candidates are:                                                                                                   
  julia_chartransform(::UInt32)                                                                                           
   @ Unicode C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Desktop 01092021\Dld\julia-1.9.3\share\julia\stdlib\v1.9\Unicode\src\Unicode.jl:47    
  julia_chartransform(::Integer)                                                                                          
   @ Unicode C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Desktop 01092021\Dld\julia-1.9.3\share\julia\stdlib\v1.9\Unicode\src\Unicode.jl:48    
  julia_chartransform(::Char)                                                                                             
   @ Unicode C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Desktop 01092021\Dld\julia-1.9.3\share\julia\stdlib\v1.9\Unicode\src\Unicode.jl:49    
                                                                                                                          
Stacktrace:                                                                                                               
 [1] top-level scope                                                                                                      
   @ REPL[98]:1                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                          
julia> Unicode.julia_chartransform(eval(a[end-1]))                                                                        
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching julia_chartransform(::typeof(cross))                                               
                                                                                                                          
Closest candidates are:                                                                                                   
  julia_chartransform(::UInt32)                                                                                           
   @ Unicode C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Desktop 01092021\Dld\julia-1.9.3\share\julia\stdlib\v1.9\Unicode\src\Unicode.jl:47    
  julia_chartransform(::Integer)                                                                                          
   @ Unicode C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Desktop 01092021\Dld\julia-1.9.3\share\julia\stdlib\v1.9\Unicode\src\Unicode.jl:48    
  julia_chartransform(::Char)                                                                                             
   @ Unicode C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Desktop 01092021\Dld\julia-1.9.3\share\julia\stdlib\v1.9\Unicode\src\Unicode.jl:49    
                                                                                                                          
Stacktrace:                                                                                                               
 [1] top-level scope                                                                                                      
   @ REPL[99]:1
```

Answer (score 1):

`×` and `⋅` are synonyms for `cross` and `dot`

```
help?> ×
"×" can be typed by \times<tab>

search: ×

  cross(x, y)
  ×(x,y)

  Compute the cross product of two 3-vectors.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> a = [0;1;0]
  3-element Vector{Int64}:
   0
   1
   0
  
  julia> b = [0;0;1]
  3-element Vector{Int64}:
   0
   0
   1
  
  julia> cross(a,b)
  3-element Vector{Int64}:
   1
   0
   0
```

```
help?> ⋅
"⋅" can be typed by \cdot<tab>

search: ⋅

  dot(x, y)
  x ⋅ y

  Compute the dot product between two vectors. For complex vectors, the first vector is conjugated.

  dot also works on arbitrary iterable objects, including arrays of any dimension, as long as dot is
  defined on the elements.

  dot is semantically equivalent to sum(dot(vx,vy) for (vx,vy) in zip(x, y)), with the added restriction
  that the arguments must have equal lengths.

  x ⋅ y (where ⋅ can be typed by tab-completing \cdot in the REPL) is a synonym for dot(x, y).

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> dot([1; 1], [2; 3])
  5
  
  julia> dot([im; im], [1; 1])
  0 - 2im
  
  julia> dot(1:5, 2:6)
  70
  
  julia> x = fill(2., (5,5));
  
  julia> y = fill(3., (5,5));
  
  julia> dot(x, y)
  150.0

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  dot(x, A, y)

  Compute the generalized dot product dot(x, A*y) between two vectors x and y, without storing the
  intermediate result of A*y. As for the two-argument dot(_,_), this acts recursively. Moreover, for
  complex vectors, the first vector is conjugated.

  │ Julia 1.4
  │
  │  Three-argument dot requires at least Julia 1.4.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> dot([1; 1], [1 2; 3 4], [2; 3])
  26
  
  julia> dot(1:5, reshape(1:25, 5, 5), 2:6)
  4850
  
  julia> ⋅(1:5, reshape(1:25, 5, 5), 2:6) == dot(1:5, reshape(1:25, 5, 5), 2:6)
  true
```

Comment: How did you come to know the last two are 'x' and '.'? Its not clear from command line print.Is there a way to get clarity.

Comment: Instead of . one question mark is seen in command line.

Comment: you can see from your output, the last two are that?

Comment: and then it's just a matter of pulling up the help file

Comment: You mean from the online documentation?

Comment: no, in the REPL (aka. the interactive julia thing in your coding environment)

Comment: @Vinod if you see a question mark instead of the characters, that means that your terminal is not able to display these characters, and might be pretty old. Maybe try opening Julia in a different terminal application like Console2, and see if the output is displayed correctly there.

Comment: @SundarR Console2 is giving same error.

Comment: Copying with clipboard command and pasting in ? help is giving correct idea

Answer (score 1):

The Windows console by default has trouble with a lot of Unicode characters, which is probably the reason you're having trouble with the display of `⋅` and `×`. There are multiple discussions about this ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379240/is-there-a-windows-command-shell-that-will-display-unicode-characters) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651975/unicode-utf-8-with-git-bash) [3](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-can-i-use-unicode-characters-on-the-windows-command-line)) on StackExchange, but in effect:

1. If you're on Windows 10 with the latest updates, run `chcp 65001` before running Julia, to get these to display properly.
2. If you're on an older version, use a different console, like the Git Bash that comes with Git for Windows, or WSL2.

The error from `Unicode.julia_chartransform(eval(a[end]))` isn't related to this, and is because you're working on the names without converting them to strings. You can try something like this instead:

```
julia> [only(String(n)) for n in last(names(LinearAlgebra), 2)]
2-element Vector{Char}:
 '×': Unicode U+00D7 (category Sm: Symbol, math)
 '⋅': Unicode U+22C5 (category Sm: Symbol, math)
```

where it will show you the Unicode codepoint value of the character, and that they come under the category of mathematical symbols.

Comment: Also download, install and configure for the terminal JuliaMono font which has good unicode support: https://juliamono.netlify.app/