# How to properly set build.gradle .kts encoding

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, build.gradle

I created a simple gradle.build.kts that logs a string. This string uses special characters.

```
plugins {
    base
}

logger.lifecycle("René Link")
```

The `build.gradle.kts` is UTF-8 encoded. UTF-8 is the default for the kotlin compiler, as far as I know. Thus it should correctly compile the script. But when I execute the build I get wrong characters printed.

```
./gradle build
> Configure project :test
RenÚ Link

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
```

I first thought it is a problem with my terminal in IDEA (I use git bash on windows), but I opened a git bash outside of IDEA and set the character set to UTF-8 as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36692549). But things are getting worse with this setting.

```
Ren▒ Link
```

How can I log a UTF-8 string with special characters in gradle?

**EDIT**

1. I checked the terminal encoding using the `locale` command.

   ```
    LANG=
    LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
    LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
    LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
    LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
    LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
    LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
    LC_ALL=
   ```
2. I checked the `build.gradle.kts` with the `file` command.

   ```
    $ file build.gradle.kts
    build.gradle.kts: Unicode text, UTF-8 text, with CRLF line terminators
   ```
3. I used `cat` to output the `build.gradle.kts` in the terminal

   ```
    $ cat build.gradle.kts
    plugins {
        base
    }

    logger.lifecycle("René Link")
   ```

   The output is ok.
4. I tried `gradle -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 build`, but this won't help either

   ```
   Ren├® Link
   ```

Since `cat` correclty outputs the `build.gradle.kts`, I assumes there is no problem with the terminal settings. I guess there must be something wrong with the settings of the Kotlin compiler that reads and compiles the script. But I can not find any documentation about that.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'é'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'cp850')` returns `'Ú'`. Check the terminal code page, set to any of ['cp1250', 'cp1252', 'cp1254', 'cp1256', 'cp1257', 'cp1258', 'iso8859_10', 'iso8859_13', 'iso8859_14', 'iso8859_15', 'iso8859_16', 'iso8859_2', 'iso8859_3', 'iso8859_4', 'iso8859_9', 'latin_1'].