# git bash displays non-latin symbols incorrectly

Tags: windows, git-bash, non-latin

when i compile java program using git bash, it displays non-latin symbols incorrectly, let me explain

i have something like this

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Тестим кириллицу в консоли");
    }
}
```

and then, if i compile this code using git bash, i'll get this:
-> https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aiza.png

I'm using UTF-8 encoding in git bash
OS - Windows

Comment: Choice of font and encoding is a compiler thing and a terminal thing. They have to match. If they don't, you get gibberish glyphs. Try piping the output through `xxd` or `od -x` or `od -c` to see the bytes the program is sending.

Comment: Git bash is broken. Use something else

Comment: You may want to check your encoding settings on gitbash, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651975/unicode-utf-8-with-git-bash

Answer (score 0):

In general, the point is that latin characters, namelly keywords are encoded by ASCII encoding standard which is supported by UTF-8 historically. However, the string in the println() method is encoded by windows-1251 encoding.

You can check it by yourself using `xxd filename` command in git bash, where 'filename' is your Class.java file. xxd (hexadecimal dump) is a command-line program that may be used to manage, convert, and display binary files on Unix and Unix-like operating systems.

So, if you change the encoding to cp-1251 in git bash, characters will be displayed correctly.

I figured this out thanks to the comments to my question.