# How to output greek symbols in c# Console Application?

Tags: c#, symbols

I'm trying to output θ (theta) on a console applicatation and I searched on Google and found that I have to use Unicode to output any greek symbols. So the code I used was:

```
Console.WriteLine("\u03B8 (deg)  R (m) \t T (kN)  FOS");
```

But instead of printing 'θ', '?' is printed. Can somebody advise me please?

Comment: cmd.exe as far as I know, cannot print unicode.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how

Answer (score 4):

If you're outputting to the console, you'll have to change your codepage to something that understands unicode. You can do this by typing  `chcp 65001` at a command prompt. You'll also have to change your font to Lucida Console or Consolas:

[image]

Edit: Well of course it's possible to do in C# as well:

```
    public static void Main()
    { 
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
        Console.WriteLine("\u03B8");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I think you'll still have to massage the font by hand (or by unmanaged code).

Comment: I am on `Win7 x64` and the console seems a bit buggy - at first I thought it didn't work after changing the font, but it corrected itself once I tabbed around a bit. Probably the window needs to redraw itself for encoding to take effect with a new font.

Answer (score 2):

See [How to make Unicode charset in cmd.exe by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109024/how-to-make-unicode-charset-in-cmd-exe-by-default)

The answers to this question explain how to set up `cmd.exe` to display Unicode characters.

Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14109166/1042555) suggests changing the registry:

1. Go to `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage]`
2. Change the `OEMCP` value to `65001`