# Polish letter in path cordova error

Tags: cordova

cmd: cordova platform add android generates error

Build failed c:\Users\?ukasz\ .cordova ...

He can't find file because I have "Ł" in users name folder which it changes to "?".
(should be c:\Users\Łukasz\ .cordova)

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the CodePage to unicode, before running

```
chcp 65001
cordova platform add android generates error
```

If this works, than you'll need to change the CodePage permanent. There is this answer:
[How to make Unicode charset in cmd.exe by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109024/how-to-make-unicode-charset-in-cmd-exe-by-default)