# unable to create superuser in django

Tags: python, django

***Every time I try to create a database this happens***

```
C:\Users\Admin8085\Desktop\src>python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superuse
rs defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Please enter either "yes" or "no": yes
Please enter either "yes" or "no": yes
Please enter either "yes" or "no": yes
Please enter either "yes" or "no": 'yes'
Please enter either "yes" or "no": yes
Please enter either "yes" or "no":
```

Comment: I dont have an answer for this behavior, but one thing you can do is, say `no` here, and then do `python manage.py createsuperuser`

Comment: either i enter 'yes' or 'no' nothing works

Comment: abort the process, and do `python manage.py syncdb --noinput ` and then, `python manage.py createuser`. My guess is, it has something to do with the database write permissions or something

Answer (score 0):

Hah, I bet it's to do with the character set.  What do you get if you run this?

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.getdefaultencoding())"
```

If your system encoding is different from the one that Python is using then "yes" in python may not equal "yes" in your terminal. :-O

Comment: See this discussion on how to change the Windows charset: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109024/how-to-make-unicode-charset-in-cmd-exe-by-default