# Python: Run windows CMD commands through python, using å,ä and ö

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

I'm trying to run the command `echo hej värld` (swedish for "hello world") through python code.

So far i have tested:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess
print subprocess.check_output("Echo hej värld", shell = True)
```

And

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
os.system("Echo hej värld")
```

Both versions return `hej vÃ¤rld`

If i simply type the command into the CMD prompt it returns the proper version, using ä.

Comment: Works on Linux (Python 2.7.3). Both versions, with the `Echo` changed to `echo`. My guess is that Windows' command line doesn't use utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Maybe [helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17177904/461597), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14109024/461597).

Comment: Even if i change the cmd encoding using `chcp 65001` (which is utf-8) before i run the command i still can't seem to print å ä ö. Now it returns `hej vÃƒÂ¤rld`.

Comment: did you try to encode to windows-1250 or windows-1252?

Comment: @user3012759
 No luck :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could do some tests on a windows 7 system. The problem is not on the execution of a command but only on the display of UTF-8 characters.

First, it works almost correctly using Python 3.4 : it can display ä without problems. So I assume you are using a 2.x version.

On a 2.x version, it is almost impossible to have proper display of UTF8 strings. If you manage to do it correctly, the driver will complain because the number of characters is different than the number of bytes.

You could find some more references here : [Windows cmd encoding change causes Python crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878972/windows-cmd-encoding-change-causes-python-crash). In particular, the referenced [Python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1602) was still active the 2014-10-02 ...

So what to do ?

The only correct solution in Windows is to use a 8bits only character set. Latin1 (windows cp 1252) should display swedish characters provided you use a `Consolas` font. <del>`CP850` is normally the OEM raster character set (in western Europe) and works also correctly.</del>

EDIT : concrete how-to

- for Python 2.7 :

  ```
  #first define a unicode string in a portable way
  utxt = u"Echo hej v\u00e4rld"
  #convert it in ANSI (whatever the current console cp can be)
  txt = utxt.encode('cp1252')

  os.system('echo ' + txt)
  ```
- for Python 3.x :

  ```
  #first define a unicode string in a portable way
  utxt = u"Echo hej v\u00e4rld"

  os.system('echo ' + txt)
  ```

Of course, if you have the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` line, you can safely write `värld` instead of `v\u00e4rld`

EDIT (4):

eryksun's comment is the proper explaination to what happens. Python 2.7 uses `CreateProcessA` meaning it wants the input of the command in what Windows uses for its ANSI code page and not the OEM code page. So for a system using Windows 1252 as its ANSI code page, you must convert the command to `cp1252`.

Latin1 (or iso-8859-1), Latin9 (iso-8859-15) and windows 1252 are almost the same character set ... but the `€` sign is the difference between them ! And if you want it under windows you must use the `cp1252` variant

Comment: Tried both 1252 and 850, using consolas no luck :( And yes, i'm using 2.7.

Comment: I can't manage to make it work :/ Did the method you describe in your edit work for you?

Comment: I tried it under windows 7 french version and it worked (see last edit)

Comment: Last edit worked! You are a god! Thanks alot :) character encoding in CMD is aweful. Edit: And just FYI, character pages seems to be independent of pythons encoding. You can use any chcp, latin1 was what did it.

Comment: Python 2 `system` and `subprocess.Popen` call `CreateProcessA`, which decodes the command line to Unicode as an ANSI string, i.e. with the encoding `ansi = locale.getpreferredencoding()`. Since the `echo` command writes unicode to the console by calling `WriteConsoleW`, the output codepage shouldn't be an issue, other than for selecting a font with the proper glyphs.

Comment: @eryksun : Thank you ! I know understand what happens ... I've edited my post with your comment

Comment: You'd have to change your system locale and reboot to practically test this. For example, by changing the system locale to Greek in the control panel's region and language settings. In codepage 1253 `'\xe4'` maps to `u'δ'`, so in Python 2 I'd expect `os.system('echo hej v\xe4rld')` to echo "hej vδrld" to the console. That's what I get for the following: `ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleOutputCP(1253);` `print 'hej v\xe4rld'`. However, decoding according to the console codepage isn't the same decoding path as what `CreateProcessA` uses. The latter is hard-coded at boot time.

Comment: @eryksun : It should break before. At line `txt = utxt.encode('cp1253')`, I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: I used the Python 2 byte string `'\xe4'`. The Unicode string `u'\xe4'` is "ä", which isn't mapped in the Greek codepage, 1253.