# I cannot see utf8mb4 characters from my database with cmd on windows

Tags: windows, cmd, character-encoding, mysql-connect, utf8mb4

This is how I connect to my database on my Windows cmd: `mysql -u mydb -h myip -p`.

It has always worked since I tried to swap my utf8 database to utf8mb4. The changes I apply with php or java work fine and I can see those characters correctly when loading from php, java or phpmyadmin but not on my cmd.

I have tried adding `--default-character-set=utf8` and `--default-character-set=utf8mb4` to the cmd connection with no succeed. It is curious, by the way, that if I run a simple sentence like `SELECT '☺';` it shows that character correctly.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried the chcp command? In the following thread they were setting cmd.exe to run unicode with this command. I would try to work with this to achieve utf8mb4 as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109024/how-to-make-unicode-charset-in-cmd-exe-by-default

Comment: Just tried it and same thing happens. It shows a `?` where it should appear the `☺`

Comment: Can you tell me how did you try?

Comment: `Windows + R` > `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K chcp 65001` and then, after the cmd opens, write: `cd c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin` and then `mysql -u mydb -h myip -p`. Also tried with `mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -u mydb -h myip -p` and  `mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -u mydb -h myip -p`. None of them worked. Thank you for your interest :)

Comment: With that you were defining the character encoding to UTF8, if I am not mistaken, however, you need UTF8MB4. You will need to find out the number needed after chcp to achieve that. I would send a question to Microsoft if I were you.

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66682 

Reading this, it looks like a bug from Mysql 5.5. Should probably update to 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the findings of danibg in the end of our brainstorming session, he has found this [link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66682) which describes that this is a MySQL bug which was applicable to 5.5, used by the op and apparently this was fixed for MySQL 5.6+

> We tested 5.6 version of client against 5.5 version of server,
>   especially with respect to non ANSI characters. The 5.6 client worked
>   as expected and the issue mentioned in this bug was also fixed.

As a result, the solution is as follows:

- create a backup and store at least 2 copies
- uninstall MySQL 5.5
- install MySQL 5.6+
- import the copy
- do a lot of tests

Comment: Mysql 6.0 does not exist at this time. But installing a 5.6+ version should do the trick. Thank you, you help me on way or another to find out what was wrong on that.

Comment: @danibg, you are perfectly right, sorry for the typo, edited my answer to fix it.