# Running Tika through tika-python in Windows produces encoding errors

Tags: windows, python-3.x, unicode, command-line, apache-tika

I have python code that extracts text from pdf files using Tika Server through tika-python. It then stores the resulting output in individual json files.

The command I run to execute my script is

```
python extraction.py <full path to some local directory>
```

I'm using python 3.5

It works perfect in different MacBookPro computers. 
It doesn´t work as expected in Windows, even using up-to-date Windows 10.

Some pdf files are processed, others produce an error such as:

```
'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 3648-3649: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have tried changing the Code Page to 65001 and changing console font to Lucida Console, based on other questions posted on Stack Overflow, including 388490 ([Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how)) and 14109024 ([How to make Unicode charset in cmd.exe by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109024/how-to-make-unicode-charset-in-cmd-exe-by-default)) and 1259084 ([What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using)).

I also tried installing ConEmu (http://conemu.github.io/en/UnicodeSupport.html) and changing the default encoding for all consoles.

Other references mention win_unicode_console (https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console) but the python patch recommended instructions are not working in my machine.

I use Anaconda as my python distribution.

I am interested in knowing how to be able to run my python code in Windows without having these encoding problems. From what I have read, this is not a problem with my python code nor with Tika Server but rather a Windows encoding issue.

Thank you all,

German

Comment: Please provide the complete traceback so that the context of the error can be determined. It may have nothing to do with printing to the console.

Comment: I normally run my code using try except blocks, so code executes. It just generates lots of useless json files. If I did not try-except, the traceback would look like the picture in next link. (http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z68hh.png)

Comment: The problem is unrelated to the console. Text files default to the system's preferred encoding. As of the 3.5, `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns the ANSI encoding from the user's Windows locale setting (e.g. codepage 1252). You need to modify how `out` is opened in extraction.py to add the parameter `encoding='utf-8'`. (For 3.6 or 3.7 a proposal to change the preferred encoding on Windows to UTF-8 is currently being debated.)

Comment: Your comment solved my problem. It is now working as expected. Also, I thought that having coding: utf-8 comment at the top of a script was supposed to specify encoding, but evidently I was wrong.

Comment: The coding spec on the first line of a script is to specify the encoding of the script file itself. For Python 3 the default encoding for scripts is UTF-8, so the coding spec isn't required for a UTF-8 file.

Comment: Shouted success before completion...: hours later I got another UnicodeEncodeError, this time associated to the print statement that I include in my try-except blocks to check if a file was correctly processed.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Wa8.png

Comment: The new error is due to the console codepage. Enable `win_unicode_console` to solve that problem.