# python subprocess encoding

Tags: python, encoding, subprocess

I'm trying to store the output of powershell in a var:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call("powershell \"Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\CurrentVersion\\\\Uninstall' -ErrorAction 'Stop' -ErrorVariable '+ErrorUninstallKeyPath'\"", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

this way, using **check_call**, it prints ok, for example:

***DisplayName : Skype™***

but this way it only prints to screen, so i have to use

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("powershell \"Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\CurrentVersion\\\\Uninstall' -ErrorAction 'Stop' -ErrorVariable '+ErrorUninstallKeyPath'\"", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

but then, using **check_output**, i get:

***DisplayName : SkypeT***

how can i work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following this post instructions:[How to make Unicode charset in cmd.exe by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109024/how-to-make-unicode-charset-in-cmd-exe-by-default?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Its possible to bypass this encoding problem

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("chcp 65001 | powershell \"Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\CurrentVersion\\\\Uninstall' -ErrorAction 'Stop' -ErrorVariable '+ErrorUninstallKeyPath'\"", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: why do you transfer output of chcp to powershell? maybe you meant && instead of | ?

Answer (score 1):

The output is a of type `bytes` so you need to either decode it to a string with `.decode('utf-8')` (or with whatever codec you want), or use `str()`, Example:

```
import subprocess
output_bytes = subprocess.check_output("powershell \"Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\CurrentVersion\\\\Uninstall' -ErrorAction 'Stop' -ErrorVariable '+ErrorUninstallKeyPath'\"", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

output_string = str(output_bytes)
# alternatively
# output_string = output_bytes.decode('utf-8')

# there are lots of \r\n in the output I encounterd, so you can split
# to get a list
output_list = output_string.split(r'\r\n')

# once you have a list, you can loop thru and print (or whatever you want)
for e in output_list:
    print(e)
```

The key here is to decode to whatever codec you want to use in order to produce the correct character when printing.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, but the result was the same...
I managed to solve it following this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109024/how-to-make-unicode-charset-in-cmd-exe-by-default?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
i'm posting an anwser with the correct code

Comment: You can also set `text=True` to obtain results as `str` instead of `bytes`, or `encoding='utf-8'` to set a specific encoding.

Comment: encoding='ISO-8859-1' worked for me.