# Encoding of characters when running powershell script as python subprocess

Tags: python, powershell, encoding, character-encoding

Currently, I'm scripting a small python application that executes a PowerShell script. My python script should process the returned string but unfortunately, I have some trouble with the encoding of special characters like 'ä', 'ö', 'Ü' and so on. How can I return a Unicode/UTF-8 string?

You can see a simple example below. The console output is `b'\xc7\xcf\r\n'`. I don't understand why it's not `b'\xc3\xa4\r\n'` because `\xc3\xa4` should be the correct UTF8 Encoding for the character 'ä'.

try.py:

```py
import subprocess
p = subprocess.check_output(["powershell.exe", ".\script.ps1"])
print(p)
```

script.ps1:

```bsh
return 'ä'
```

I adopted my PowerShell script in some ways but did not get the desired result.

1. Added `"[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8". Result: b'\xc3\x83\xc2\xa4\r\n'`
2. Returned `return [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("ä"). Result: b'195\r\n131\r\n194\r\n164\r\n'`

Who can help to get console output of `'ä'` for my upper script?

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/a/49630797/5320906

Answer (score 1):

I used "`pwsh`" because I ran it on mac, you can use "`powershell.exe`" in your code
Try this:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.check_output(["pwsh", ".\sc.ps1"])
print(p.decode('utf-8'))
```

For more: You can read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html).

[Working Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOba6.png)

Comment: I have installed pwsh and tested it with both and added print(p.decode('utf-8')) to my try.py script. I get from pwsh the string b'\x84\r\n' and from powershell b'\xc7\xcf\r\n'. Result for pwsh is:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
b'\x84\r\n'   print(p.decode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 0: invalid start byte`