# Why is Python's subprocess output different than cmd's of a PTC command?

Tags: python, cmd, python-3.7, mks-integrity, ptc-windchill

Im using **Python 3.7** and the `im viewissue <itemID>` [command](https://support.ptc.com/help/integrity_hc/integrity111_hc/en/index.html#page/IntegrityHelp%2Fim_viewissue.html%23) of **Integrity Client 12.5**. When I query and item using this in cmd, I get every detail perfectly decoded, no unknown bytes or hexadecimal values. However, when I try using

```
subprocess.run(<command_args>, capture_output=True).stdout.decode(encoding='utf-8')
```

I get this exception:

```
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 528: invalid start byte"
```

And the problem is there with every other encoding type I tried. But when I use the exact same command in cmd I don't see any problematic character, everything is displayed correctly and if I checked right it uses UTF-8 as well.

There are some encodings that can display that character (e.g. **Windows-1252**), however the decoded character is different than it should be. Byte **0xb5** translates to "**µ**" but originally that should be an "**Á**", as it is in the cmd output.

I tried using different encodings, different functions but couldn't manage to find what causes this difference between the two platforms' output or how I can overcome the problem aside from manually mapping the characters to the correct ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question [use unicode for cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49630797)

Comment: You cannot have tried very many encodings; the vast majority of legacy 8-bit encodings will happily accept pretty much any bytes you can throw at them. Of course, if you choose the wrong one, you'll get [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), but without access to the tool you are running and information about your system encoding, we can't guess which one is correct.

Comment: https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#b5 lists all the 8-bit encodings known to Python and which character it maps to in each of them. The correct encoding is one of cp850, cp852, cp857, cp858. (Disclosure: I am the author of that page.)

Comment: Thank you for the asnwers, cp852 worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all in the comments who helped.

The solution was finding which code page cmd was using with `chcp` or `mode`, then using that as the specified encoding in the Python script like

```
stdout.decode(encoding='cp852')
```

It was `cp852`.