# Java with maven, netbeans

Tags: java, maven, output

I'm currently developing a proyect about chess. Main idea is to use it on console as CMD.
It currently works with array[8][8], i store the "chess pieces" on it. But the main problem is:
When i want to print an emoji as "♜, ♞, ♝, and so on", output displays the emojis as **?**.
*I have already tried some things like UTF-8, Emoji-Java library,* changing the Fonts of output console with compatible Fonts... I've tried for hours, i have searched around the internet, i can't find anything... If you help me i'd appreciate it.

```
 [?][?][?][?][?][?][?][?]//♜, ♞, ♝, ♛, ♚, ♝, ♞, ♜.  
 [null][null][null][null][null][null][null][null]//Null= available space to move
 [null][null][null][null][null][null][null][null]
 [null][null][null][null][null][null][null][null]
 [null][null][null][null][null][null][null][null]
 [null][null][null][null][null][null][null][null]
 [null][null][null][null][null][null][null][null]
 [null][null][null][null][null][null][null][null]
//Please ignore the null values, it's going to be fixed when the problem is solved...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complicated, very complicated, and it differs by the OS and it also differs by the version (windows 7 vs 10), and it differs by the patch level (eg windows 10 before and after patch 2004 for example).

So let me **save you hours of further heartache by suggesting that you use a UI** instead where you can control the underlying character set. For example, using Swing or JavaFX.

---

However, if you insist on using the console then you need to take a number of steps.

The first being to use a `PrintWriter` in your code to write out characters using the correct encoding:

```
PrintWriter consoleOut = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
consoleOut.println("your character here");
```

The next step is to pre-configure the console to use your character set. For example in windows you might use the chcp command before starting your jar file:

```
chcp 65001
java -jar .....
```

But not only that, you should use the `Dfile.encoding` flag when you start your jar:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar yourChessApplciation.jar
```

Now assuming you got all those steps right it might work, but it might not. You also need to ensure that all your source files are encoded in UTF-8. I won't go into that here because it differs by this IDE, but if you are using something like Netbeans then you can configure the source encoding in the project properties.

I would also encourage you to use the Unicode character definition rather than the actual symbol in your code:

```
//Avoid this, it may fail for a number of reasons (mostly encoding related)
consoleOut.println("♜");
//The better way to write the character using the unicode definition
consoleOut.println("\u265C");
```

Now even with all this you still need to ensure that your chosen console uses the correct character set. Here are the steps to follow for powershell: [Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt / Windows Powershell (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/1270000) Or for windows cmd you can take a look here: [How to make Unicode charset in cmd.exe by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109024/how-to-make-unicode-charset-in-cmd-exe-by-default)

---

So with all of those steps completed you can compile this code:

```
PrintWriter consoleOut = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
consoleOut.println("Using UTF_8 output with the character: ♜");
consoleOut.println("Using UTF_8 output with the unicode definition: \u265C");   
consoleOut.close();
```

And then run your compiled jar file in your console (Powershell in this example) something like this (You wont need to use `chcp 65001` if you configured the powershell console correctly):

```
chcp 65001
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar yourChessApplciation.jar
```

And the output should give the following result:

> Using UTF_8 output with the character: ♜
>
> Using UTF_8 output with the unicode definition: ♜

But it might still fail to show correctly, in which case see my opening section about using a UI, or try a different console... It's complicated.