# CMD.EXE in Windows Service Problem with national characters

Tags: c#, windows, encoding, service, console

When I run cmd.exe using process.start() as desktop application there is no problems with national characters in the StandardOutput - they are displayed correctly in the console output. But when the same is working as windows service the national characters coming from the service are displayed incorrectly. I guess something must be done with locale but cannot figure out when and how. Or may be I'm wrong at all. Please advice.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109024/how-to-make-unicode-charset-in-cmd-exe-by-default