# Unreadable characters in github desktop bash

Tags: git, unicode, windows-console, github-desktop

[image: Chinese characters are not displayed properly in github desktop bash]

I installed GitHub desktop. I open its bash and run `git log`. Chinese characters are not displayed properly. How can I fix that?

I searched a lot of articles but they all use git in linux or other git tools.

Comment: If using `cmd.exe` as your console (as opposed to a different console application), then can you try enabling a unicode font in the console, e.g., `cmd> chcp 65001`  ...As [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/737677/127971)?

Comment: Another option is to use a different console (which would have its own settings, features and limitations), e.g., https://git-for-windows.github.io/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how)