# How to print out ellipsis in console?

Tags: c#

The problem is simple:

```
Console.WriteLine("…");  // Unicode ellipsis U+2026, not three periods
```

Is shown in console as:

```
:
```

How to print it out correctly? Is it possible?

PS:
Visual Studio 2017, Console Application, Raster Fonts in console window.

Comment: What font do you use on your console? Each font might display the same unicode character differently

Comment: Related (not a dupe):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379240/is-there-a-windows-command-shell-that-will-display-unicode-characters

Comment: In `Unicode` it is shown.`Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;`

Comment: I have RasterFonts in console.

Comment: Use `...` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to change the encoding on the Console

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Then you can write it out

```
Console.WriteLine("\u2026");
```

or your version

```
Console.WriteLine("…");
```

Comment: It will print out some crazy stuff:  Иж

Comment: @eocron I just tried it, the output is as expected, what else are you doing?

Comment: Nothing. Just two lines in Main method. The first you wrote and the second and third.

Comment: @eocron could it be because you have other fonts loaded or .Net is different in Russia? Check the UTF8 reference, this works in the English version.

Comment: Yeap, it was problem related to font. Raster Fonts is what given me the pain (I restarted example with other font predefined). Thanks!